# XML hierarchy with Boost::serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, format, hierarchy

I've recently begun to use Boost::serialization for research work and although it is extremely powerful and easy to use, I still have a little trouble with the final xml format. I have a hierarchy of classes and when serialized, each subclass is nested within it's own tag in the xml output. This subClass tag is created because of the use of `boost::serialization::base_object`. Does anybody know how to keep the base and sub classes in the same level of xml hierarchy ?

Ex : the current format

`<baseClass> 
        <attr>value</attr> 
        <subClass> 
            <otherAttr>value</otherAttr>
        </subClass>
    </baseClass>`

the target format :

`<baseClass> <attr>value</attr> <otherAttr>value</otherAttr> </baseClass>`

Comment: Do you need it to do this (e.g. is another program expecting specific output), or is this just to increase readability?  See comments on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931535/boost-serialize-serialize-data-in-a-custom-way - In particular, the suggestion of using [Boost.Karma](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks folks. Btw, to answer @Merlyn 's  question, yes it is for readability :) otherwise, text archive would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost.Serialization is not intended for being a mechanism to write to a *specific* file format. It is a way to dump a class's data to a file, and then read that data with *this* program again. The format is not something that should concern you.

If you are using a specific file format, then what you want, as Merlyn suggested, is a [Boost.Karma](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma.html) generator.